# malnormal subgroup of amalgamated free product

Tags: geometric-group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

Consider the amalgamated free product $\Gamma = K\ast_{H\simeq H'} L$. Let $A$ be a malnormal subgroup of K i.e, for all $k\in K\setminus A$, $k^{-1}Ak \cap A ={1}$.
Is A malnormal in $\Gamma$?

I was trying to do this by writing elements in normal form but completely stuck.
For example let $g\in \Gamma\setminus A$ and $m\in A$, then i was trying to prove that $g^{-1}mg$ does not belong to A.
if we write $g$ in normal form in $\Gamma$ using right cosets representative of $H,H'$ in $K,L$ respectively  then $g^{-1}$ will be in normal form using left cosets of $H,H'$ in $K,L$, then $g^{-1}mg$ will no longer be in a normal form using right cosets or left cosets.
I don't know how to handle this.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: When you wrote "for all $k \in K \setminus H$" I presume you meant "for all $k \in K \setminus A$"?

Comment: yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you meant what I suggested in my comment regarding malnormality of $A$ in $K$, this isn't true. The idea for a counterexample is that $A$ could have a nontrivial intersection with $H$, and $A \cap H$ could be identified with some subgroup of $H'$ that is a proper, normal subgroup $L$.

To turn that into an actual counterexample:

- Let $K$ be the rank $3$ free group $K = \langle a \rangle * \langle b\rangle * \langle c \rangle$,
- Let $A < K$ be the rank $2$ free factor $A = \langle b \rangle * \langle c \rangle$ which is malnormal in $K$,
- Let $H < A$ be the rank $1$ free factor $H = \langle c \rangle$,
- Let $L$ be the rank $2$ free abelian group $\langle c' \rangle \oplus \langle d \rangle$,
- Let $H < L$ be the rank $1$ direct factor $\langle c' \rangle$.

And now amalgamate $K$ and $L$ using an isomorphism $\langle c \rangle \approx \langle c' \rangle$.

Comment: Thanks  for  this example. What will happen if $A\cap H$ is also identified with a proper malnormal subgroup $H'$ ? Also in particular what will happen if we take double of $K$ along  subgroup $H$ and $A$ is malnormal in $K$, and $A\cap H$ is malnormal in $H$.

Comment: sorry in previous comment i mean $A\cap H$ malnormal in $L$. Also in double situation i mean $A\cap H$ is malnormal in K.

Comment: I think there's something like that which should be true. That would be a different question for a different post, though.

Comment: Can you please tell what kind of results are known or some references?

Comment: I don't know of any such reference, sorry. But I suspect that it's not hard to work out. Perhaps write a followup post here.